# Incorect output using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I got this homework question, after taking a course on Udemy I still cannot figure out how to get the right output like the Solution.

Furthermore: how can I make it more efficient. How can I do it without use explicit loops, but use list/dictionary comprehensions instead.

This is what I do:

```
def group_permutation_values(permutations_list): 

    dic = {}
    f = lambda x: x[1]
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(permutations_list, key=f), f):
        dic[key] = list(group)

    return dic

    pass

results = [
    ((1, 2, 3), -4),
    ((1, 3, 2), -4),
    ((2, 1, 3), -2),
    ((2, 3, 1), -2),
    ((3, 1, 2), 0), 
    ((3, 2, 1), 0)
]
print(group_permutation_values(results))
```

This is what I got:

```
{
    -4: [((1, 2, 3), -4), ((1, 3, 2), -4)],
    -2: [((2, 1, 3), -2), ((2, 3, 1), -2)],
     0: [((3, 1, 2), 0), ((3, 2, 1), 0)]
}
```

And the expect output:

```
{
    -4: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2)],
    -2: [(2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1)],
     0: [(3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key function to `groupby` only determines how values are grouped; the function is not used to alter the group elements themselves. Just because you group by `element[1]`, doesn't mean that the groups will only contain `element[0]`, you get the whole tuple.

All you need to do is extract that first nested tuple from each element of a group when creating your list value:

```
dic[key] = [t[0] for t in group]
```

so where `list(group)` returns `[((1, 2, 3), -4), ((1, 3, 2), -4)]`, the above list comprehension instead produces `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2)]`.

You can replace your outer `for` loop building the dictionary from the `groupby` results, with a dictionary comprehension:

```
def group_permutation_values(permutations_list): 
    f = lambda x: x[1]
    sorted_list = sorted(permutations_list, key=f)
    return {k: [t[0] for t in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, f)}
```

**However**, using `groupby()` is the wrong tool here. `groupby()` requires that you sort the input first, which costs you in performance. Sorting is a O(N log N) operation, but bucketing your tuples into a dictionary can instead be done in O(N) linear time simply by looping over your input list and appending to a list per entry:

```
def group_permutation_values(permutations_list):
    grouped = {}
    for a, b in permutations_list:
        grouped.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
    return grouped
```

This can't be turned into a dictionary comprehension, but is more efficient none-theless. Comprehensions are not magic bullets, they are just a syntax to create a containers (lists, dictionaries, sets) by processing each element from an iterable. Yes, they are a bit more efficient than the equivalent `for`-loop-with-add-to-container-operation, but they are still subject to the usual algorithmic time complexities.